# Unable to serve static resources with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have a Sprint Boot Gradle application that has the following structure: [Screenshot of project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VP5f.png)

**Project Structure**

```
/build.gradle
/src/main/resources/static/css/default.css
/src/main/java/com/expensalyze/ExpensalyzeApplication.java
/src/main/java/com/expensalyze/web/TagController.java
```

Basically I have my css file located at `src/main/resources/static/css/default.css`. I am expecting to fetch this file at `http://localhost:8080/css/default.css`.

As per [this link](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) and also the [spring boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content), the above setup is all that's needed. But I am getting a 404 when I try to visit `http://localhost:8080/css/default.css`

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.2.RELEASE'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.2.RELEASE')
}
```

**ExpensalyzeApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.expensalyze")
public class ExpensalyzeApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExpensalyzeApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**TagController.java**

```
@Controller
public class TagController {
    @RequestMapping("/tag") // This works properly
    @ResponseBody
    String tag() {
        return "tag";
    }
}
```

- I haven't added any explicit resource mapping configuration code.
- My controller method mappings are working properly

The bare minimum code to reproduce the issue can be found [here](https://github.com/simplycsk/expensalyze/commits/static-res-test) in the branch `static-res-test`. You can run the project with these steps (requires JDK 8):

```
$ ./gradlew clean build
$ java -jar build/libs/expensalyze.jar
```

If you visit http://localhost:8080/tag it works, but if you visit http://localhost:8080/css/default.css it is not found!

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't, ever, use EnableWebMvc in a Boot app. It removes all the autoconfiguration of MVC done by Spring boot, and puts you in charge of everything. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, searching (now) for `@EnableWebMvc` in the Boot Docs, I find that it will do exactly what you said! I didn't go through the docs thoroughly enough to understand that. Thanks for pointing that out. Removing that annotation fixed the issue. Please add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't, ever, use EnableWebMvc in a Boot app. It removes all the autoconfiguration of MVC done by Spring boot, and [puts you in charge of everything](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration).